# Django List View get_queryset not rendering all objects

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following ListView which I want to use also for filtering the results

```
class Membresias(ListView):
    model = Cliente
    template_name = 'main/membresias.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        nombre = self.request.GET.get('nombre')
        if nombre is None:
            return Cliente.objects.all()
        else:
            return Cliente.objects.filter(nombre = nombre).values()
```

when the 'nombre' variable is not None it show the results,
**PROBLEM**: but when I leave it blank or is None, it does not show any records at all and according to the validation the queryset should retrieve all the records.

Here is part of the html for the table

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
                <th scope="col">Activo</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for cliente in object_list %}
                <tr>
                <th scope="row"><a href="{{ cliente.get_absolute_url }}">{{cliente.id}}</a></th>
                <td>{{cliente.nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{cliente.email}}</td>
                <td>{{cliente.telefono}}</td>
                {% if cliente.activo == False %}
                <td><input type="checkbox" readonly class="form-check-input mt-1" id="Estatus" disabled value={{cliente.activo}}></td>
                {% else %}
                <td><input type="checkbox" readonly class="form-check-input mt-1" checked id="staticEmail" disabled value={{cliente.activo}}></td>
                {% endif %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the *truthiness* of `nombre` and if the `nobre` is `None` or empty (`''`), work with:

```
class Membresias(ListView):
    model = Cliente
    template_name = 'main/membresias.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        nombre = self.request.GET.get('nombre')
        if not nombre:
            return Cliente.objects.all()
        else:
            return Cliente.objects.filter(nombre=nombre)
```

Comment: hey, I tried printing what I was getting and if  I leave the search blank I get a ( ' ' ) , so I tried your solution and it was not working, I changed it to 'if not nombre' and it is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in `return Cliente.objects.filter(nombre = nombre).values()` the `.values()` method transforms the query from a model instance into a paython dictionary which may be the problem here,
try droping the .values()

```
return Cliente.objects.filter(nombre = nombre)
```